# Android ConstraintLayout performance improvements - Missing in action

Tags: android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I have created a custom view and inserted logging for an estimated performance comparison

```
public class CustomInAppKeyboard extends LinearLayoutCompat  {

    private static final String TAG = "MyKeyboard";

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);

        if(BuildConfig.DEBUG){
            Log.e("CustomInAppKeyboard", "w:" + widthMeasureSpec + " :: " +  MeasureSpec.toString(widthMeasureSpec));
            Log.e("CustomInAppKeyboard", "h:" + heightMeasureSpec + " :: "  + MeasureSpec.toString(heightMeasureSpec));
        }

    }

    public CustomInAppKeyboard(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public CustomInAppKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public CustomInAppKeyboard(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(context, attrs);
    }
    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {

        LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.keyboard_alphanumeric, this, true);
    }

}
```

then using start & end times of "MyKeyboard" logs... I end up with the following values:

- ConstraintLayout withguides 14.32
- ConstraintLayout with chains 13.62
- LinearLayout (nested weights) 4.88

That was based on these xml layouts files in the following gist:
  - https://gist.github.com/CrandellWS/fc7946ea653cf90828580b3c00d8da57

So how can I get the ConstraintLayout to render as fast as the nested LinearLayout? What could I do differently or change to get the ConstraintLayout to more closely match the LinearLayout performance?

["actual" Keyboard layout files are known to be different](https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-layout-files)

Note that there is an inability to use Systrace on my physical device https://stackoverflow.com/a/52836747/1815624 ... hence the rudimentary performance test method...

Answer (score 1):

In order to answer this question, we'll have to take a detour for that.

I am assuming that you have read about how `ConstraintLayout` works internally, so let me just stick to the point. Yes, I agree that `ConstraintLayout` is slower than `LinearLayout` but it's only when the number of child views are less in number.

When you start building larger layouts, say which consist of 20-30 Views, the `ConstraintLayout` comes handy. If you'll then use `LinearLayout` or any other layout, say `RelativeLayout` then you'll end up using multiple child `ViewGroups` and your Layout Graph might end up like this

```
LinearLayout(orientation vertical)
   -> SomeChildView (let's say a TextView)
   -> LinearLayout (orientation horizontal)
            -> ChilView 1  -> ChildView 2
   -> ImageView
   -> ButtonView
   -> ViewGroup (FrameLayout)
           -> ImageView1
           -> idk, maybe TextView?
```

and the list goes on.

Now, with such kind of Layout, traditional `ViewGroups` will end up computing more number of views than `ConstraintLayout`

So, we can come up with a conclusion that, no ViewGroup is perfect!! We just have to use them in accordance to our need..

**Bonus!!** `ConstraintLayout` should be avoided inside `RecyclerView` because it calls `onMeasure()` multiple times than any other layout.

I once made some [research](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46597935/8164116) on `ConstraintLayout` back then before applying it to my project.

Comment: appreciate the input so I up voted you but this does provide any solution to improving the performance so I can not accept it as the answer. thanks

Comment: That's really sweet of you @CrandellWS, but this is what I'm trying to convey, you can not tune up `ViewGroups`. It's just the efficient implementation of a `ViewGroup` which makes it any "Faster" as compared to others. I get it that my answer did not satisfy your needs, I would love to be notified if there is any possible practice to do so. :)